# I have recently started learning hibernate and I got the following doubts

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, frameworks, relational-database

I have recently started learning hibernate and I got the following doubts

Correct me if I am wrong.

1. If hbm2ddl.auto is set to **create**, every time hibernate tries to interact with any table, that table will be dropped first.
2. Because hibernate drops a table every time it interacts with it, if I want to update a record I cannot configure hbm2ddl value as create.

Answer (score 0):

The table is not dropped and recreated every time hibernate interacts with it -- it's dropped and recreated when the SessionFactory is initialized.  This usually means when your application starts up.  So if you are doing some tests where you want to start with a clean database each time the application runs, setting hbm2ddl.auto to "create" would be reasonable.

For more, see the [community documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl) and [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/438146/685522).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 0):

If you will configure value as create you can update a record , but when your application is down , and you will restart it all changes will disappear.
So actually in this case its better to use update.

In case of update it only updates schema , you can define some schema sql file and use it on database side , and simply configure hbm2ddlauto as update.

Here are possible values of hbm2.ddlauto:

- validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
- update: update the schema.
- create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
- create-drop: drop the schema when the SessionFactory is closed
     explicitly, typically when the application is stopped.